# Intercept traffic before interface

Tags: kernel, process, network-interface, traffic

I am wondering if it is possible to intercept traffic emmited by a process before it goes through an interface on my host? How could I try and do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is what a packet filter is.

A common packet filter is implemented in firewalls.  On Linux, the most common is `iptables` which can take ***many*** rules that can filter and redirect traffic in any direction.